# F# Fable Best Way to return Null/None

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I'm working with Fable. I am doing an array look up, and if the key does not exist I want to return null or similar. Since it's built on Javascript which is inherently type unsafe, I'm not sure if I should go all in making the return value an option type, but is probably what I'll do

I have a function that looks like this

```
    let getDataFunction() : obj =
        let data = dostuff() //Returns Map<string, obj>
        match data.TryFind key with
        | Some result  -> result //Is a boxed obj of 'a
        | None -> box null
```

However when I try to call it

```
let parsedData = unbox getDataFunction()
```

The function returns an Option type with Some{value: null}.
It works fine if instead of null, I use "" or 0 or false

What should I be doing to be able to either make that return None or null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can update the function so that it either returns `None` or `Some` not null value like this:

```
let getDataFunction() =
    let data = dostuff() //Returns Map<string, obj>
    data.TryFind key
    |> Option.bind Option.ofObj
```

`Option.ofObj` returns `None` for a null value. Combing that with `Option.bind` ensures we only have one option, not a nested option of an option.

Comment: Thank you, apparent Some{value: null} when outputted to console is equivalent to None in F# code. So that had me very confused.